# Toolbar button wont get activated when pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, toolbar

I've programmatically added a button to my toolbar but it doesnt work. Whats wrong with my code?  Its not even pressable.  Its like its just a picture on the toolbar.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   //Toolbar send button
   UIView *buttonContainer1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
   buttonContainer1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"send.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   const CGSize button1Size = [button1 sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
   [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-40, 27, button1Size.width, button1Size.height)];
   [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [button1 setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
   [buttonContainer1 addSubview:button1];

}

-(IBAction)button1Action:(id)sender{
   textField.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
   textField.text = @"the message was sent";
   [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. What should I set my sizeThatFits: parameter to?

Comment: Can you find width and height of your button?

Comment: Well it's a resizable image in an asset catalog so it changes based on the device used

Comment: Code seems fine. check 1) frame of button. 2) userInteractionEnabled on buttonContainer1.

Comment: I set userInteractionEnabled to YES on buttonContainer1 and button 1, still not being activated.

Comment: U want buttonContainer1 to act as a toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for Tool bar for your textfield. I have been using it in my code

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 60.0, 30.0);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(button1Action:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
keyboardDoneButtonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil]];
textfield.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView;
```

Comment: While this code may be useful as an alternate approach, this answer really doesn't make any effort to answer the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one important line of code at the very end of `viewWillAppear`:

```
[self.view addSubview:buttonContainer1];
```

FYI - this code should be in `viewDidLoad`, not `viewWillAppear`. `viewWillAppear` might be called more than once so you would end up adding more than one button.

And nothing about your code has anything to do with a toolbar.